# while transforming attributes to element with XSLT how ignore only the attributes in parent element

Tags: xml, xslt, dom

I am using XSLT in order to transform certain xml that contains all values formated as attributes to another xml keeping the values as child element. In my xml there are two children name, one is aa and another is bbb. The transformation is working perfectly when I check the values for both aa and bbb. The problem is I want to delete/ignore the attributes found in the parent element of these children element.

I am showing below the must two significant tentatives I have tried so far. The first one is my original idea but I want it avoiding the parent attributes (exactly "cod" and"package" in my xml).

The second is the consequence of searching around but it is actually driving away from what I want. Nevertheless, the second tentative can help me express that I am probably missing either certain "pattern" or some "comand" to skip the attributes from root element.

MyApp.java

```
Path f = Paths.get("C:\\in1.xsl");
//Path f = Paths.get("C:\\in2.xsl");
InputStream resourceAsStream = Files.newInputStream(f);
StreamSource xsl = new StreamSource(resourceAsStream);
Transformer transformer;
transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsl);
StreamSource in = new StreamSource(
              new FileInputStream("C:\\my_xml.xml"));
StreamResult out = new StreamResult(System.out);
transformer.transform(in, out); //in1 produced out1 and in2 produced out2
```

my_xml.xml

```
<c:product xmlns:c="myapp">
       <c:item cod="789">
              <c:aa name="024" value="123"/>
              <c:bbb name="0105" value="123456"/>
              <c:bbb name="0122" value="T"/>
              <c:aa name="071" value="00000001"/>
       </c:item>
       <c:item package="123" cod="11111">
              <c:aa name="002" value="753"/>
              <c:aa name="003" value="456"/>
              <c:bbb name="0146" value="147852"/>
       </c:item>
</c:product>
```

in1.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" standalone="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
       <xsl:template match="@*">
              <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
                     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </xsl:element>
       </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="*">
              <xsl:copy>
                     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
              </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

in2.xls (source [Copy XML file contents except for root node and attribute XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733948/copy-xml-file-contents-except-for-root-node-and-attribute-xslt))

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

out1.xml (I don’t want cod element in first item neither I want package and cod in second item)

```
<c:product xmlns:c="myapp">
<c:item>
<cod>789</cod>
<c:aa>
<name>024</name>
<value>123</value>
</c:aa>
<c:bbb>

<name>0105</name>

<value>123456</value>

</c:bbb>

<c:bbb>

<name>0122</name>

<value>T</value>

</c:bbb>

<c:aa>

<name>071</name>

<value>00000001</value>

</c:aa>

</c:item>

<c:item>

<package>123</package>

<cod>11111</cod>

<c:aa>

<name>002</name>

<value>753</value>

</c:aa>

<c:aa>

<name>003</name>

<value>456</value>

</c:aa>

<c:bbb>

<name>0146</name>

<value>147852</value>

</c:bbb>

</c:item>

</c:product>
```

out2.xml (well, there is a single point here that I tried to take advantage to express my self: the root element receives a different treatment. If I find how to treat the root element by ignoring their attributes and mixed with the rest of in.xls I will probably discover my solution)

```
      <aa name="024" value="123"/>

      <bbb name="0105" value="123456"/>

      <bbb name="0122" value="T"/>

      <aa name="071" value="00000001"/>
```

```
      <aa name="002" value="753"/>

      <aa name="003" value="456"/>

      <bbb name="0146" value="147852"/>
```

Comment: This is rather confusing: could you post the exact output you **want** to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing (!) you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:c="myapp"
exclude-result-prefixes="c">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c:item">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<product>
   <item>
      <aa>
         <name>024</name>
         <value>123</value>
      </aa>
      <bbb>
         <name>0105</name>
         <value>123456</value>
      </bbb>
      <bbb>
         <name>0122</name>
         <value>T</value>
      </bbb>
      <aa>
         <name>071</name>
         <value>00000001</value>
      </aa>
   </item>
   <item>
      <aa>
         <name>002</name>
         <value>753</value>
      </aa>
      <aa>
         <name>003</name>
         <value>456</value>
      </aa>
      <bbb>
         <name>0146</name>
         <value>147852</value>
      </bbb>
   </item>
</product>
```

---

Note that the `c:item` element getting special treatment (2nd template) is **not** the root element.

Comment: I can't imagine better and more precise answer than that. I don't know what was unclear but your guess is correct and your answer as well. I choosing your answer as definitive answer.
P.S.: I am bit curious: would that be possible with XLST and XLS to provide the answer in json instead of XML? Exactly same input file but output in json without firstly transforming from in xml to out xml using xls and then from out xml to out json with tradional ways in java? So the input would be xml and the output would be json without the attributes from c:item

Comment: I believe it should be possible. I suggest you ask this in a new question - and show the exact JSON output you expect to get.